# How can I change "127.0.0.1:8000 / localhost:8000" to my desired url. (laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I'm using laravel and I don't know how to customize the default url which is "127.0.0.1:8000" or "localhost:8000" to my desired url.

My expectation is to change **127.0.0.1:8000** to **sample.dev** when I do **php artisan serve**

Do I really need to move my projects to **htdocs** or **www**?

Please help...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**NOTE**: This is just to answer the question, scroll down more to see the other approach where we would use `.test` instead of `.dev`, so we won't get SSL errors.

---

## To change the default host to your desired one

1. Go to the project directory where `artisan` is located.
2. Run the following command:

   ```
   php artisan serve --host=some-domain.test --port=anyPort
   ```
3. Make sure the host exists in your `etc/hosts` file. To add an entry to the hosts file edit `/etc/hosts/` with your favorite editor and add this line to your current `/etc/hosts/` file.

   ```
   127.0.1.1  sample.dev
   ```

   If I change my `/etc/hosts` file it, it would look something like this:

   ```
   127.0.0.1   localhost
   127.0.1.1   sample.dev // Added line.

   // More custom hosts here.
   ```

If you run the command on port 80, it would throw an error. because it's very likely that you also use the Apache service. To make the command work you have to either:

- **A**: Stop the Apache service using `sudo service apache2 stop` on
  Ubuntu (May change based on distros).
- **B**: Use a different port, since it's for development purposes, I
  suggest you stick to `8080` or any other port that you won't use.

Now after you decided you want to stick to port `8080`, the command above will change to the following:

```
php artisan serve --host=sample.dev --port=8080
```

**NOTE**: Those steps above are for your case, if you run those commands above, it won't work in modern browsers and will throw an `SSL Error`. because as of Chrome version 63, you cannot use the `.dev` domain **without** an SSL certificate. which there are ways to set up on the local environment, but not really necessary since you're in development mode anyways.

BUT, there is a domain specifically for development purposes, called `.test`, so do the steps above but change the domain to `.test`, the commands above will look like the following:

```
php artisan serve --host=sample.test --port=8080
```

This is very useful for development purposes, since you don't need to add a `VirtualHost` for every new project you make.

Comment: Thanks Sir. It works perfectly!!. But can I ask Sir, is there any short way of this "php artisan serve --host=sample.dev --port=8080"?

Comment: @Joshua That's as short as it gets, I suggest you create a bash alias if you don't want to type it all in.

Comment: @Akar please mark this answer as "correct" if it answered your question :)

Comment: The `--host` option actually changes which address the server will listen on, and isn't directly related to the address in the browser. The default is to listen on localhost (127.0.0.1), which means it can't be accessed from outside the machine. Using  `--host=0.0.0.0` would listen on all addresses for the local machine. If you have multiple IP addresses that route to the machine, it can be used to specify which to listen on, e.g. `--host=192.168.2.100`.

Answer (score 5):

### To Change the Hostname

The *only* required step is to add an entry to your system's [`hosts`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system) file:

```
127.0.0.1 sample.test
```

Your site will be available from `http://sample.test:8000`<sup>1</sup> when you run `php artisan serve`.

---

### To Remove the Port

To remove `:8000` from the url, you need to be listening on the default port<sup>2</sup> for HTTP:

```
php artisan serve --port=80
```

Now your site will be available at `http://sample.test` from a browser on the same machine.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I changed the example to [`.test`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.test), which is a **reserved** top-level domain (TLD). `.dev` is owned by Google and will cause SSL errors when developing with the builtin PHP server used by `artisan` due to [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) being enabled for the entire `.dev` TLD.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>This only works if there are no other applications already using port 80 on your machine, e.g. another webserver like Apache, Nginx, IIS, etc.</sub>

Comment: You forgot that he must setup a virtualhost entry to point it to his Laravel project folder path which is serve by php artisan.

Comment: @Ronald that's not required for `php artisan serve`

Comment: Yes, that's what I pointed out in your answer :) the php artisan serve command is missing :)

Comment: The question only asked how to change the url, but I can clarify further.