# How to change url of the project in vsc

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

I want to open two or more project at the same time in vsc code but there have the same url http://localhost:8000
how to change it.?

thanks,[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change "127.0.0.1:8000 / localhost:8000" to my desired url. (laravel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53192680/how-can-i-change-127-0-0-18000-localhost8000-to-my-desired-url-laravel)

Comment: APP_URL is just telling you what you have in that env value.  It it not related to how you serve the site or anything to do with vscode